# apt-get: use alternative sources.list

Tags: debian, apt

In my `/etc/apt/sources.list` I have:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main
```

Now I need to get source of a package from `jessie` (testing). How can I specify a different `sources.list` when I call `apt-get source` ?

```
apt-get source package-name
```

**PS:** I don't want to modify `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or I want to run `apt-get` as a user who cannot modify the system wide sources list.

Comment: I would donwload the source package manually

Comment: @hek2mgl - could you please provide an example how you would download the package manually ?

Comment: Which package do you want?

Comment: @hek2mgl - for example `ipython-notebook` from `jessie`

Comment: `ipython-notebook` will getting built from the `ipython` source package. You have svn access here: http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/python-modules/packages/ipython/trunk/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by setting the `Dir::Etc::sourcelist` configuration setting:

```
apt -o "Dir::Etc::sourcelist=/path/to/your/sources.list" source package-name
```